# When clicking on the card in Flutter, I want to give a border color and the card can be selected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
  class PopUpCard extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const PopUpCard({super.key, required this.title});
}
  Container(
              child: Card(
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                
                )),
              ),
```

I'm calling the widget I created on my homepage.

```
 Row(
                children: const [
                  PopUpCard(
                    title: '9',
                  ),
```

[image]

For example, when the card number 9 is clicked, as in the image, I want a red border around it.

Comment: You can use decoration on Container

Comment: What I want is not to color around the card. Coloring its surroundings when the user clicks on a card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, declare a boolean variable at the top of that widget:

```
bool isSelected = false;
```

then set the border on the container based on that bool:

```
 Container(
      height: 80,
      width: 80,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
       border: isSelected ? Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2,) : null
       ),
      child: Card(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 85, 144),
        child: Center(
            child: Text(
          widget.title,
          style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        )),
      ),
```

then wrap your widget with `GestureDetector` widget, toggle that isSelected in the `onTap` method property, and update the state

```
 GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
    isSelected = !isSelected;
    SetState(() {});
    },
    child: Container(
          height: 80,
          width: 80,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
           border: isSelected ? Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2,) : null
           ),
          child: Card(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 85, 144),
            child: Center(
                child: Text(
              widget.title,
              style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            )))),
```

Answer (score 1):

This part will do the job,

```dart
 Container(
  height: 80,
  width: 80,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 85, 144),
    borderRadius: isTapped ? BorderRadius.circular(24) : null,
    border:
        isTapped ? Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 4) : null,
  ),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text("Button"),
),
```

```dart
class TFW extends StatefulWidget {
  const TFW({super.key});

  @override
  State<TFW> createState() => _TFWState();
}

class _TFWState extends State<TFW> {
  final data = List.generate(4, (index) => 9 + index);

  /// because `data` is List of int
  int? selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          ...data.map(
            (i) => GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                selectedIndex = i;
                setState(() {});
              },
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                height: 80,
                width: 80,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 85, 144),
                  borderRadius:
                      selectedIndex == i ? BorderRadius.circular(24) : null,
                  border: selectedIndex == i
                      ? Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 4)
                      : null,
                ),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("Button"),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use `AnimatedContainer`

Comment: I can make the card selectable now, thanks. However, when I click on the selected card again, I can't unselect it.

Comment: to deselect, make it false again. if you like to select one, you can use `int selectedIndex` instead of bool. just provide true/false on `borderRadius` and `border`.

Comment: So how do I ensure that only one card can be selected? For example, the user pressed card number 9 and selected it. If he hits the number 10 card, only 10 will be selected.

Comment: As for the image, every container having different number, you can create a nullable int, and on pressed  select that number. Are you doing it for Row/list of items like 1to 10?

Comment: I created a widget called CardWidget. Include a String title; I have assigned a variable. Then I called this CardWidget 4 times in a row and wrote numbers in the title part.

Comment: what is your data here?  I mean how you've decide the number of card?

Comment: Test the `TFW`  widget, you will get the idea. Pass a bool on `PopUpCard` that will decide whether it is selected or not

Comment: I updated my question. This is how I value each card.

Comment: Just pass a bool or selected string as shown on Gwhyyy answers

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating temp variable as below

```
String selectedTitle = '';



GestureDetectore(
   onTap:() {
setState((),{
     selectedTitle = widget.title;
});
},
    Container(
              height: 80,
              width: 80,
              child: Card(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 85, 144),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder( 
        side: BorderSide(
          color: widget.title == selectedTitle ? Colors.red : Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  widget.title,
                  style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
              ),),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<int> listSelected = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Test")),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              if (listSelected.contains(index)) {
                listSelected.remove(index);
              } else {
                listSelected.add(index);
              }
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 80,
              width: 80,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: listSelected.contains(index)
                      ? Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2)
                      : null),
              child: Card(
                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 19, 85, 144),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    index.toString(),
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
```